# Datatables display Id from database in attribute

Tags: datatables

I am using data column like this

```
columns: [
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'address' },
            {
               "className":      'options',
               "data":           null,
               "render": function(){

                    var btnDropdown = '<div class="btn-group">';
                        btnDropdown += '<button class="btn btn-xs green dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> Actions <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>';
                        btnDropdown += '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';
                        btnDropdown += '<li><a title="" href="render id here"><i class="icon-docs"></i> New Post </a></li>';
                        btnDropdown += '</ul>';
                        btnDropdown +='</div>';

                   return btnDropdown;
                }
             }
        ]
```

and in the third column i want to have a button with the attribute id of the selected row from the database I choose.

something like

```
<button id='5'>edit<\button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can render your edit button with any (unique/primary key) attribute in table. I am assuming name as unique key. then you can create it using php or any other language easily like this.

E.g.

`<?php`
 
`echo "<a href='edit.php?name='".$name."'">Edit</a>`
`?>`

Comment: yes in php approach. but in ajax, how can i render that result?

Comment: You have to do the same thing in PHP and after that you can load the entire php container using ajax.

Comment: I updated my question with the actual code. how can i render the id in <a title="" href="_render id here_">